# Binding to Collection in SPring MVC 2.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am maintaining a Spring MVC Web apps written in spring 2.5.  Now I want to add some enhancement into it but
currently encountering some problem.

I created a select box and set the multiple option to true and disabled it also.
The only way to populate the the select is thru making some ajax call.

```
<form:select  path="dataFiles" multiple="true" disabled="true">
</form:select>

publiv class MyData{
 private List<String> dataFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
 //getters
 //setters
}
```

After the ajax call returns, I automatically select each options.  I dont want user to edit this anymore.

But my problem is, during form submit they dont get binded into my commandbean.  Is there any workaround for this?

I tried removing the disabled attribute and everything work well, but my problem is, it violates my requirements.

Any hints about this?

Comment: If the field is disabled, are you sure the browser is even sending the data?

Comment: Hi SkaffMan,

I notice that too in my firebug.  Anyway, I think all disabled tags are not participating in form submission.  Thank you..

Comment: I agree if your field is disabled I don't believe the data gets sent over on form submition.  Capture the javascript submit event and enable the field.  This will keep the field disabled for the user until they submit and should send it over.

Comment: Hi ballmw,  many thanks... this is what I did... on jquery for submission, I hijack it and enabled all form input tags... thanks thanks thanks...=)

Answer (score 0):

Using InitBinder annotation and CustomerCollection utilty provided by Spring framework.

I would write something like below in my controller.

```
@InitBinder()
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception
{
   binder.registerCustomEditor(Collection.class, new CustomCollectionEditor());
}
```

Refer Spring documentation about binders here

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion